# PHP produced HTML content rendered as plaintext

Tags: php, html, apache, mime-types, lamp

I have been working on a project locally (in MAMP) and just decided to upload it to my LAMP server online. This server was working previously, but after uploading all of my new content it is not rendering the HTML, just showing the source code as plain text.

All PHP seems to be working fine as it's displaying the correct content.

To no avail, I tried explicitly setting the content type with `header("Content-Type: text/html")`. When I remove the PHP includes and instead use HTML directly however, it works fine.

I'm using an **index.php** file that includes a few others:

```
<?php

include_once 'header.php';

include_once 'inc/window.php';
createWindow();

include_once 'footer.php';

?>
```

Maybe my **header.php** file might contain some clues as well:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!doctype html>

<html>

<?php

include_once 'inc/files.php';
$files = json_decode(getFiles($ids));

?>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <?php

    $title = '';
    foreach($files as $i=>$file){
        $title .= $file->content . ' ';
        if(count($file) > 1 && $i < count($file)-1) $title .= '+ ';
    }

    ?>

    <title>* <?php echo strtolower($title); ?></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
```

My environment is running PHP5+ (5.3 I believe?), Ubuntu, and Apache2. I have webmin and SSH access as well.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Jonny

Comment: These two statements seem to say opposite things:1)but after uploading all of my new content it is not rendering the HTML, just showing the source code as plain text.
2) All PHP seems to be working fine as it's displaying the correct content. --- please explain what is or is not working more clearly

Comment: What I mean is that it is running through the PHP code and correctly reading information from the database, running all necessary logic, and outputting the correct HTML. It is just not being rendered in the browser as HTML should - it's appearing as if I were using "View Source" on the page.

Comment: is it on the web? can we get the url

Comment: In that case, please dump the headers that are being sent along with the page. One way is to use firebug in firefox.

Comment: also, please be sure you are not looking at the page in "view source" mode

Comment: Zak, I'm not viewing it in source mode, but here is the header dump:

Host: site.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: __utma=255071832.497188835.1366748350.2; __utmc=255071832; __utmz=255071832.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); PHPSESSID=

Comment: Sorry, had to trim some long variables in there like the PHPSESSID to allow the comment.

Dagon, I can't share the URL at the moment, unfortunately -- soon, though ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Wow - figured it out after a little bit more debugging!

The issue was related to the content type being set in the files.php file:

```
if(!headers_sent()) header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

For some reason, this was being encountered before the headers for the page were sent.

I'm not sure why this wasn't happen on my local site, and if anyone can speak to that, I'll gladly up-vote that answer! :) I've removed it for now, though as it's not really necessary.

Thanks S/O